# FindNextPrinterChangeNotification misses events?

Tags: c#, .net, events, unmanaged, print-spooler-api

I am using `FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification` and `FindNextPrinterChangeNotification` to catch printing events. However I have noticed that `FindNextPrinterChangeNotification` does not reliably returns all the events. I have found a guy with the same problem [in this article](http://microsoft.public.win32.programmer.gdi.narkive.com/jqGFylbY/is-findnextprinterchangenotification-reliable-to-catch-all-notifications).

Basically, when I debug my program, or put Sleep command like his suggestion when processing an event, `FindNextPrinterChangeNotification`skips a lot of events. Also, most of the time I get a lot of SPOOLING status events but miss the DELETED status event (sometimes I get it, but most of the time I cannot), even though I already push the jobs to a Queue for later processing.

Does anyone have this problem too? Also, I am trying the Microsoft PDF Printer, The `NumberOfPages` increases as the SPOOLING events come, but the `NumberOfPagesPrinted` does not. Is it intended?

**EDIT** After some investigation, the events are not actually gone. If I call another print job, the previous events are fired (including the DELETING/DELETED status of previous print job). Can you please suggest what is the problem?

Here's the code for calling `FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification`:

```
    //We got a valid Printer handle.  Let us register for change notification....
    _changeHandle = FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification(_printerHandle, (int)PRINTER_CHANGES.PRINTER_CHANGE_JOB, 0, _notifyOptions);
    // We have successfully registered for change notification.  Let us capture the handle...
    _mrEvent.SafeWaitHandle = new Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeWaitHandle(_changeHandle, true);
    //Now, let us wait for change notification from the printer queue....
    _waitHandle = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(_mrEvent, new WaitOrTimerCallback(PrinterNotifyWaitCallback), _mrEvent, -1, true);
```

And this is for the `FindNextPrinterChangeNotification`:

```
    _notifyOptions.Count = 1;
    _notifyOptions.dwFlags = PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS_REFRESH;
    int pdwChange = 0;
    IntPtr pNotifyInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
    bool bResult = FindNextPrinterChangeNotification(_changeHandle, out pdwChange, _notifyOptions, out pNotifyInfo);
```

Comment: What parameters are you passing to FindFirst and FindNext? Are you requesting ALL notifications? Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162723(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @bizzehdee I have included the code in my question. I request for `PRINTER_CHANGE_JOB` only.

Comment: I also added setting the flag `PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS_REFRESH`, and I received a lot more events, but there is still no consistent DELETING Status.

Comment: The answer from alital is likely correct. By telling `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` not to reset the event, you're going to miss any events that occur during your callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue then I tried:

```
_waitHandle = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(_mrEvent, new WaitOrTimerCallback(PrinterNotifyWaitCallback), _mrEvent, -1, true);
```

with:

```
_waitHandle = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(_mrEvent, new WaitOrTimerCallback(PrinterNotifyWaitCallback), _mrEvent, -1, false);
```

(false arg in the end)
and seems to work now

Comment: I believe you copied the wrong line of code. I don't think you meant to say you replaced `FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification` with `RegisterWaitForSingleObject`.